# Android studios how to pass a context from mainactivity to another class

Tags: java, android-studio, main-activity

I have this problem, how do i use a function from MainActivity in my class Dialog_findname, i have to pass the context of main in line: `vardadienas = main.loadedfile(MainActivity.this);`

```
public class Dialog_findname extends AppCompatDialogFragment {

  private EditText findName;
  private findnameDialogListener listener;
  private List<VDienas> vardadienas = new ArrayList<>();
  private Finder finder = new Finder();
  private MainActivity main = new MainActivity();


  @Override
  public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    vardadienas = main.loadedfile(MainActivity.this);
  }
```

And this is my MainActivity function I want to call in the other class:

```
public List<VDienas> loadedfile(Context ctxt){
    FileInputStream fis = null;
    try {
        fis = openFileInput(FILE_NAME);
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(fis);
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(isr);
        String line;
        reader.readLine();

        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
            VDienas VissGads = new VDienas();
            String[] tokens = line.split(";");


            VissGads.setDatums(tokens[0]);
            VissGads.setMenesis(Integer.parseInt(tokens[1]));
            VissGads.setDiena(Integer.parseInt(tokens[2]));

            for (int i = 0; i < Integer.parseInt(tokens[3]); i++) {
                VissGads.setVards(tokens[i + 4]);

            }
            vardadienas.add(VissGads);
        }

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally {
        if (fis != null){
            try {
                fis.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    return vardadienas;

}
```

I tried to look up for similar questions, but i still couldn't understand how to :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First**, you can't create an Activity with the following:

```
private MainActivity main = new MainActivity();
```

it should be started with `Context.startActivity()`, you can read more about it at [Activity documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity).

**Second**, you have the following method:

```
public List<VDienas> loadedfile(Context ctxt) {
  ...
}
```

so, you can't call it with the following inside of Fragment:

```
 vardadienas = main.loadedfile(MainActivity.this);
```

because `MainActivity.this` is referencing to instance of MainActivity but your fragment is not an instance of activity.

You need to call the method with the following:

```
 vardadienas = main.loadedfile(getContext());
```

where `getContext()` referring to Activity where the Fragment attached.

---

You better move the `loadedfile(Context ctxt)` to its own class as an util class so you can reuse the method from any other class. You can make something like this:

```
public class FileUtils {
  private FileUtils() {} // this prevent class being instantiate.

  // we need to make it static so it can be accessed without
  // creating an instance of the class.
  // of course, you can use singleton. But it's another topic
  public static List<VDienas> loadedfile(Context ctxt) {
    ...
  }
}
```

then you can use the method with something like this:

```
vardadienas = FileUtils.loadedfile(getContext());
```

Comment: Thanks now I understand and i also had a mistake: I didn't pass the context to openFileInput. So the correct way context.openFileInput

Answer (score 0):

i think, u have to call this Function on ur MainActivity.

```
vardadienas = main.loadedfile(this);
```

or check MainActivity.class

Comment: If u pass `this` then u get error : loadedfile(...) in MainActivity cannot be applied to (com.example.firstapp.firstapp.Dialog_findname). I think the error comes from creating : private MainActivity main = new MainActivity(); in non-activity class

Comment: have u tried 
private MainActivity main = new MainActivity();
main.class